# matching number in python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match numbers with regex in python3.5
while re.match() works well, like this:

```
re.match(r"\d+(\.\d+)?", "12323.3 + 232131.2")
>>><_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 7), match='12323.3'>
```

re.findall() did not return what I expect(I want ["12323.3","232131.2"]):

```
 re.findall(r"\d+(\.\d+)?", "12323.3 + 232131.2")
 >>>['.3', '.2']
```

please someone tell me why. Thanks.

Comment: Don't capture the inner group: `"\d+(?:\.\d+)?"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are capturing parentheses, findall returns all captured groups.  You are only capturing the portion beginning with the `.`.

Try:  `r"(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)"`

or capture nothing:

`r"\d+(?:\.\d+)?"`